# Jasmine - When to use toContain() or toMatch()?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, tdd

I was studying about TDD and unit testing using Jasmine JS and I have a question about their methods.

I found two methods and would like to know what is the difference.

```
describe('Teste do toContain', () => {
    var name = 'Lucas de Brito Silva'
    it('Deve demonstrar o uso do toContain', () => {
        expect(name).toContain('Lucas');
    });
});
```

```
describe('Teste do toMatch', function () {
    var text = 'Lucas de Brito Silva'
    it('deve validar o uso do toMatch', () => {
        expect(text).toMatch('Brito');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is partly what they operate *on* but also what they will do.

Here is the example usage from [version 2 of Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) (but this runs the examples using the latest version):

```js
it("The 'toMatch' matcher is for regular expressions", function() {
  var message = "foo bar baz";

  expect(message).toMatch(/bar/);
  expect(message).toMatch("bar");
  expect(message).not.toMatch(/quux/);
});

describe("The 'toContain' matcher", function() {
  it("works for finding an item in an Array", function() {
    var a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

    expect(a).toContain("bar");
    expect(a).not.toContain("quux");
  });

  it("also works for finding a substring", function() {
    var a = "foo bar baz";

    expect(a).toContain("bar");
    expect(a).not.toContain("quux");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/boot.min.js"></script>
```

It does demonstrate what they can do.

- [`toContain`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/matchers.html#toContain) will work on both arrays and strings. It will essentially be the same using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) - the array or string will be checked if it has an *item* (for arrays) or a *subsequence* (for strings) that matches the argument. `expect(something).toContain(other)` will be roughly like checking `something.includes(other) === true`.
- [`toMatch`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.4/matchers.html#toMatch) instead uses a regular expression. So, first of all, it only works on strings, not arrays. Second, if given a string as an argument *generates* a regex from it. So, `expect(something).toMatch(other)` will actually be resolved as if `new RegExp(other).test(something)`. This does mean that if you want to use it for simple string matching you should be careful to not use special characters:

```js
it("The 'toMatch' matcher generates a regex from the input", function() {
  var message = "foo\\dbar";

  expect(message).toMatch(message);
});

it("The generated matcher will obey regex restrictions", function() {
  var pattern = "foo\\dbar";

  expect(pattern).not.toMatch(pattern);
  expect("foo4bar").toMatch(pattern);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/3.4.0/boot.min.js"></script>
```

Here, the value of the `message` string is `foo\dbar` but if you generate a regex from that, then it *wouldn't* match the same string, since `\d` denotes a digit - `foo4bar` will match but not `foo\dbar`.